# Center iframe in joomla template

Tags: css, joomla2.5

I have been trying to center a youtube video in a joomla template (J51_Oxygen - Default). Does anyone know the best way to do this? I can't seem to override the templates and I am not sure where to put the css for the templates.

I can align it right in the html, but can't align middle.

Any tips or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto;`?

Answer (score 0):

In your article editor, simply click alongside the iframe and use the 'center justify' editor button,

OR

add the following styles inline on a div around the iframe:

```
text-align: center
```

OR

add the following styles to the iframe itself:

```
margin: 0 auto
```

OR

add an ID or a class and append styles to the bottom of the template's primary stylesheet,

OR

do that and [add a custom stylesheet](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page) to your template.